# Efficient numeric operations on my object model

Tags: c, compiler-construction, interpreter, compiler-optimization, vm-implementation

I am developing a dynamic language and a virtual machine, my object model looks like:

```
typedef struct {
    int tag;
    union {
        int64_t  n;
        double_t d;
        void    *p;
    } _v;
} value;
```

Based on the tag value (an enum) I can interpret the _v union field.
A compile time macro can also define double_t as double or float for maximum efficiency.

In order to simply the object model a lot of dynamic languages instead of keep integer arithmetic and floating point arithmetic separated, just use a double and perform all numeric operations on it.

In there any performance advantage in keep integer/float arithmetic operations separated like in my case? Is there any other advantage? (other then a simplified object model with all the simplification that can derive from that).

Comment: What will you do to support size calculations, modulo arithmetic, ... ?

Comment: It doesn't really have anything to with "performance" or "efficiency", it's all about how the languages are designed. Do the language have only a single numeric data type? Do it have different integer and floating point data types?

Comment: I bit more information about likely target would be useful. On x86 these days I don't think there is much speed difference (if any) between `float` and `double`.

Comment: To the close-voters: how is this question “primarily opinion based”? It’s asking for *facts*. I get “too broad” (unfortunate, but that’s SO). I don’t get the un-explained downvote either.

Comment: Asking about performance always requires looking at the actual machine that this runs on, so use a profiler. Concerning the integer versus floating point math, they strongly differ in the way that they operate, just consider float values like NaN or Inf for example.

Comment: It is a dynamically typed language, so user can just write: var a = 1; or var b = 1.0; (In this case a will be tagged as int and _v.n will be used, while b will be tagged as float and _v.d will be used to store its value).

Comment: Floating point and integers are not interchangeable: Many 64 bit integers can't be stored as `double`, most `double`s can't be stored as integers, and even for values that are shared between the two, there are various operations that behave differently. This is not a performance concern but a correctness concern. If the language has separate int and float types (Lua doesn't, but it appears your language does), the VM must reflect that.

Comment: Even with 32bit integers and doubles you get trouble. While every 32bit integer can be represented by a double, not every result from an operation of two 32bit integers can. So you have to jump through hoops to get multiplication mod 2^32 working correctly.

Comment: @KonradRudolph in my opinion this question is opinion based because you or OP or anyone else can really decide which representation performs better by benchmarking the various choices against a representative set of tests. Without having a real interpreter code written and without interpreting real examples all you or anyone else can say are opinions or facts observed in different environments, different languages and different test sets. Even JVM optimizations are based on benchmarks not on contemplation above 8 lines of code